# Maven dependency problem

Tags: maven, jstl

I tried to convert non-maven project into a maven project.

Project works quite well, in one jsp page system gives :

java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects cannot be cast to org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.ImplicitObjects

Anybody has any suggestion on that ? or Any good maven dependecy tool you know to manage the system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For "a good maven tool to manage the system" try [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). Start from this simple report:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: jetty uses jsp-api 2.1 and whole my legancy application build-on jsp-api 2.0. ex : standard 1.0.6 gives above error : java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects 
cannot be cast to org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.ImplicitObjects

What i did : I fixed download standard 1.0.6 source and fixed it and make a jar again. Now it seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem when I upgraded an old project.

Here is how I fixed it :
exclude jstl, servlet-api, ... in the pom.xml file:

replace the taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

with

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

In the file web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
                         "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="MyProject">
```

replaced with

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
```